# Angle indication

Tags: geometry-nodes

The curve should indicate the angle between the floor and the pillar (cube). I managed to do something, but I don't like spheres. It should be a curved cone or something. It is not necessary to rely on the nodes that I have shown, you can make something of your own.
If you make a number in the middle of the curve that shows the angle, it will be "A+" (or 5+ if you from Europe) :D
[image]

UPD:

I can handle the definition of the angle myself. I just need to figure out how to put the object in the middle of the curve, and how to make the curve more attractive. Something like this:
[image]

UPD2:

Ok, I figured out how to display the angle size (but if you can do better, show me), so the angle number is no longer needed. All that remained was to make the curve smoother.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Just checking.. Have you considered the shipped MeasureIt add-on? Its angle displays are renderable...

Comment: @RobinBetts Perhaps it should have been clarified that add-ons are not suitable.

Comment: You could choose any other mesh-instance (e.g IcoSphere) and diminish the scale of instances as they go from the start to the object. For the numbers use e.g. MeasureIt addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

you can customize a few things like the arrow size, length, font size and positioning of the angle.

i formed the arrow just by using the curve radius at the end and giving them some values.

[image]

Comment: Incredible. But can you please add blend-file? Because I don't quite understand the input group. Some of them have a scale input, some do not.

Comment: thank you. If you would have provided your blend file in the question (so that i didn't have to build everything on my own) -  i would add my blend file to my answer. the input group is just doubled a few times so that the node setup isn't too messy (and it is already messy) ;) just look for the input group and you will find that every input is used.

Comment: Attached blend-file

Comment: Аnd sorry for going off topic. How do you make such low weight gifs?

Comment: the app i am using is called "giphy capture" - it is a free mac app. I have no idea whether there is the same for windows or the system you are using. The blend file attached won't help me now...because i already built the whole tree on my own, but thank you anyway.